# IE7 wont filter AJAX returned value using $(data).filter

Tags: jquery

I am using this code:

```
$.get('getdetails.php?gid='+getid, function (data) {


           //query the jq object for the values
           var person = $(data).filter('NAME').html();


// this works fine and shows the content from the getdetails.php page
alert (data);


// this shows nothing

alert(person);


});
```

and here is the getdetails.php bit

```
echo"<NAME>barry</NAME>";
```

this works 100% in chrome, FF and IE9 but not at all in IE8 or 7.

Please help!

Comment: please be more specific with your answer? Ill have a google for $.parseXML but i would like more info from you if thats ok?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle that illustrates this?  Are there any errors in IE8's developer toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason your returning XML instead of JSON?  If you can switch, you can use `JSON.parse` to covert to native object.  If you have to use JSON, you can use `getElementByTagName`.

You can query XML like it is the document's DOM.  Look at w3school documentation for more info.

Maybe you should try to use JSON because it consumes way less bandwidth than XML.

Comment: I strongly recommend *against* using w3scools for more information on anything whatsoever. It is full of errors.